# Authorize.net Accept Hosted page 'billing country' value is offset

Tags: iframe, authorize.net

I'm implementing the Authorize.net Accept Hosted form, which seems to work fine.

I understand that there are basically zero options for style/formatting customizations, but there is an issue I'm seeing on MacOS in Chrome (seems OK in FF/Safari) where the text for the 'Billing Country' is offset and overlaping the label for the select box:

[image]

Is this a known issue and/or is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you can fix it on your end. This is a CSS issue that surfaced with a recent Chrome release, it started with Google Chrome version 86.0.4240.75, previous versions of Chrome and other browsers does not shows this issue.